# Sort by color after sorting alphabetically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with around 50 sheets. I'd like to write a module that sorts them alphabetically then moves sheets with black tabs to the end after a tab called "Closed =>".

```
    Sub sortsheets()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    WS_Count = WB.Sheets.count


'Below will sort alphabetically    
    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        For j = 1 To WS_Count - 1

            If UCase(Sheets(j).name) > UCase(Sheets(j + 1).name) Then
                Sheets(j).Move after:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End if

        Next j
    Next i


' Move closed tab to the end
    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        If UCase(Sheets(i).name) = "Closed =>" Then
        Sheets(i).Move after:=Sheets(WS_Count)
        End If
    Next i

' Below needs to iterate through the sheets and move all black sheets to the end   

    For i = 1 To WS_Count

        For j = 1 To WS_Count

            If Sheets(j).Tab.ColorIndex = 1 Then
                Sheets(j).Move after:=Sheets(WS_Count)

             End If
        Next j
    Next i


    End Sub
```

The problem is that the last step that moves the black sheets to the end ruins the alphabetical order. I think that's because while it continues to loop it's coming across black sheets that were already moved to the end is moving them again. How can I prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier if you reverse your order of operations and do the color sort first.  I would sort the sheets into multiple collections by tab color.   Then at the end, you can sort each one of these collections alphabetically.

Note: typed this on my phone, so keep an eye out for typos and such ;)

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortSheets()
    Dim wb As Workbook, Sheet As Worksheet,  CloseSheet As Worksheet, BlackTabs As New Collection, OtherTabs as New Collection

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Sheet in wb.Worksheets 
         If Ucase(Sheet.Name) = Ucase("Closed =>") Then Set CloseSheet=Sheet

        Select Case Sheet.Tab.ColorIndex 
        Case 1
            Sheet.Move After:=Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
            BlackTabs.Add Sheet
        Case Else
            OtherTabs.Add Sheet
        End Select
    Next

    If BlackTabs.Count >= 1 Then SortAlpha BlackTabs
    If OtherTabs.Count >= 1 Then SortAlpha OtherTabs

CloseSheet.Move After:=Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub SortAlpha (ByRef SortSheets as Collection) 
    Dim i as Long, j as Long
    For i = 1 To SortSheets.Count
        For j = 1 To SortSheets.Count - 1
            If UCase(SortSheets(j).name) > UCase(SortSheets(j + 1).name) Then
            SortSheets(j).Move after:=SortSheets(j + 1)
        End if

    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Been wanting to try out using `Collections`. Thanks for the example, I'm going to go through it Monday.

Comment: No problem - if you get stuck or get any errors let me know, I haven't tested the code.  I chose to go with select case because i wasn't sure if you had other colors to sort by, so you can easily add more color options later.  Or you can change it to an if block if you want. Also, just corrected an error where  I copied  some of your original code that wouldn't work in this context ;)